# Generate Code without Dependencies by Dumping Class or Inlining Methods

Tags: compiler-construction

I'm implementing a sort of compiler that will produce a bunch of class files. These classes will make use of short static helper methods that are defined as methods of a Util class.

This means that a user of my compiler will need the Util class on the class path in order to use the lib. I would like to avoid that requirement.

There are two solutions that I can see, but I don't know how to implement either. There might be other alternatives.

1. take the Util class' bytecode and write it to a class file in the same directory. This would mean that the code is there when those classes execute.
2. instead of generating INVOKESTATIC calls to the Util class' methods, find an automated way to insert the bytecode of these methods at compilation time.

What's the best way to go about this? Thank you!

Comment: There's not a lot of detail here - a third, simpler option could be that your compiler carries the source for the Util class within it and emits it into the user's target directory, either as a separate file or as part of the normal compiler output.

Comment: That certainly is an option! I could improve this further by finding the class file at compile time and just copying it to the output directory. Thank you, I think I'll try that.